# Variable scope jQuery access variable outside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

Let's say I have 3 functions for 3 buttons(+/- and "Add to cart")

- One is a click event attached to the + button (increases value)
- Second is attached to the - button (decreases value)
- Third is attached to the "Add to cart" button

the result (the value of the input field) is declared as a global variable and is changed within the functions

Now, in order for me to add items to the cart using the "Add to cart" button, the button will need to know what the value of the input field is.

My question is this:

How do I access the value of the input field if it changes within the first & second functions?

Dummy code:

```
let value;

$('.inc').on('click', function() {
     value = 1;
});

$('.dec').on('click', function() {
     value = 0;
});

$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function(){
    // take value and send it to cart
});
```

NOTE: I have googled this already. Asking for a push to the right direction.

```
let increaseValueBtn = $('button[data-action="inc"]');
let decreaseValueBtn = $('button[data-action="dec"]');
let newValue;

increaseValueBtn.on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const productId = $(event.currentTarget).data('product-id');
    const $el = $(`#qty-${productId}`);
    const minQty = parseInt($el.data('quantity-min'), 10);

// updates value
    newValue = $el.val(parseInt($el.val())+1);
// makes decrease btn clickable
        if(newValue.val() > minQty) {
             newValue.siblings(decreaseValueBtn).prop('disabled', false);
        }
});

decreaseValueBtn.on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const productId = $(event.currentTarget).data('product-id');
    const $el = $(`#qty-${productId}`);
    const minQty = parseInt($el.data('quantity-min'), 10);

// updates value
    newValue = $el.val(parseInt($el.val())-1);
// if quantity is less than min qty than make decrease btn unclickable
    if(newValue.val() == minQty) {
            decreaseValueBtn.prop('disabled', true);

        }
});



$('.card-btn').on('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
        var pro;
        qty = 0;
        const productId = $(event.currentTarget).data('product-id');
        const minQty = $(event.currentTarget).data('min-qty');
        const product_this = $(event.currentTarget);
        pro = { "action": "add", "fastcart": "1", "product_id": productId, "qty[]": newValue };
        qty += Number(newValue);
        console.log(newValue.attr('value'));

        //var check = checkBeforeAdd(pro);
        // modal.open();
        error = 0;
        addToCart(pro);

        // document.getElementById('modal').setAttribute('id', 'previewModal');
        product_this.addClass('is-added');
        product_this.find('span').text('Added');
        setTimeout(function () {
            product_this.removeClass('is-added');
            product_this.find('span').text('Add');
        }, 2500);
});
```

Comment: Just use the `value` variable. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Barmar my thoughts exactly but for some reason it doesnt work within my actual project

Comment: What does not work? Show what does not work.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons in each class? There's just one global variable for all of them.

Comment: Also, `+` and `-` seem like they should be adding and subtracting, not just setting the variable to a specific number. So `+` should do `value++`, and `-` should do `value--`, and you need to initialie the variable to a number.

Comment: yes, the value is dynamic in my project, so when i initially declare value it should be a number?

Comment: made an edit, hope it makes my q a bit more clear